# .Net/SQL Insert and Select on datetime2 not matching

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, azure-sql-database

I have a piece of code that inserts a data sample ([id + datetime2] +...) in sqlAzure database.

Later for each call I do a select to know if the primaryKey is already in DB [id + datetime2] so I update it, otherwise I do an insert.
The problem is, the select doesnt return anything but the insert will get a dupplicated key error. (!?)

I created a sample of code reproducing my problem, not every time but most of it.

If I replace

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
```

by

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = date;
```

It will work, but I would like to understand why select and insert command don't match.

```
//CODE - BEGIN
//.NetCore 2.2
//SqlDatabase Azure

var date = DateTime.Now;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date); //{19:33:22.7727095}
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Answer (Id , Date) VALUES (@Id, @Date)";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

/*DB
**IdDevice  Date
**1 2019-04-18 19:33:22.7733333
*/

//Retry
command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Answer where Id = @Id AND Date = @Date;";
var exist = command.ExecuteScalar();
if (exist == null)
{
    throw;
}
//CODE - END
```

This is just a quick sample to reproduce the behaviour, I use the exact same parameter for the insert + select but the select will not return anything.
Maybe .net Datetime is converted to SqlDateTime for the insert and in SqlDateTime2 for Select...

Comment: your data in Id column insert -1 in db, and its right your select not work! is it right in column Id in db store -1?

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", value.Date); //{19:33:22.7727095} in this line what is value?

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue`. Create a parameter with a specific type, precision and set its value.

Comment: @hassan.ef my bad, its '1' in db, the problem if localized on the date ;)

Comment: @AmitYadav my bad again, mistake between the real code and sample code, the value is DateTime.Now

Answer (score 3):

`AddWithValue` infers the `SqlDbType` from the supplied .NET type as `DateTime` rather than `DateTime2`. The fractional seconds are then truncated to a precision of 3 and rounded to 1/300 second to match the less precise parameter data type. You will see this less precise value if you query the database without the `WHERE` clause.

No truncation/rounding occurs with the explict `SqlDbType.DateTime2` because .NET `DateTime` and `SqlDbType.DateTime2` both support fractional seconds with a precision up to 7.

This is yet another reason to [avoid `AddWithValue`](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Mixing datetime/datetime2 types can also result in unexpected behavior as illustrated by your `SELECT` query. `datetime2` has a higher data type precedence than datetime so the fraction seconds value is compared using the `datetime` actual 1/300 second value extended to greater precision rather than the rounded/truncated one. Consider these T-SQL examples:

```
--these values compare not equal because the datetime value of 1/300 is actually .003333333333...
DECLARE @datetime datetime =   '2019-04-19T00:00:00.003';
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '2019-04-19T00:00:00.003';
IF @datetime = @datetime2 PRINT 'EQUAL' ELSE PRINT 'NOT EQUAL';
GO

--these values compare not equal because the datetime value is actually .006666666666...
DECLARE @datetime datetime =   '2019-04-19T00:00:00.007';
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '2019-04-19T00:00:00.007';
IF @datetime = @datetime2 PRINT 'EQUAL' ELSE PRINT 'NOT EQUAL';
GO

--these values comare equal because the datetime value is .010000000000...
DECLARE @datetime datetime =   '2019-04-19T00:00:00.010';
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '2019-04-19T00:00:00.010';
IF @datetime = @datetime2 PRINT 'EQUAL' ELSE PRINT 'NOT EQUAL';
GO
```

Although this comparison behavior [breaking change](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-2016-and-azure-sql-database-v12-breaking-change/) can be controlled by running in [database compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) 120 or lower, it would be best to simply match SQL types. This will provide the best performance and future proof your code.

**EDIT:**

The same behavior can be demonstrated with .NET parameters of mismatched types. Below is a PowerShell example.

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$connection.Open()
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE dbo.Answer (Id int NOT NULL, Date datetime2 NOT NULL);", $connection)
[void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()

$command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Answer (Id, Date) VALUES (@Id, @Date);"
[void]$command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1)
[void]$command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", [DateTime]::Parse("2019-04-19T00:00:00.003"))
[void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Answer where Id = @Id AND Date = @Date;"
$exists = $command.ExecuteScalar()
# not exists
if($exists -ne $null) { Write-Host "exists" } else { Write-Host "not exists" }

$command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Answer (Id, Date) VALUES (@Id, @Date);"
$command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = 2
$command.Parameters["@Date"].Value = [DateTime]::Parse("2019-04-19T00:00:00.007")
[void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Answer where Id = @Id AND Date = @Date;"
$exists = $command.ExecuteScalar()
# not exists
if($exists -ne $null) { Write-Host "exists" } else { Write-Host "not exists" }

$command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Answer (Id, Date) VALUES (@Id, @Date);"
$command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = 3
$command.Parameters["@Date"].Value = [DateTime]::Parse("2019-04-19T00:00:00.010")
[void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Answer where Id = @Id AND Date = @Date;"
$exists = $command.ExecuteScalar()
# exists
if($exists -ne $null) { Write-Host "exists" } else { Write-Host "not exists" }    

$connection.Close()
```

Comment: For sure, as i say if i use 
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = date;
It works fine, but i dont understand how using the same Sql.Parameter  (added with AddParamerWithValue) can give different result used in a Select and Insert command...

Comment: @CarlosBarroso, I'll add to my answer to explain why the unexpected results with the same parameter value.

Comment: I do perfectly understand your example but it's not really my use case.
To resume
`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Datetime.Now);
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Answer (Date) VALUES (@Date)";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Answer where Date = @Date;";
command.ExecuteScalar(); //return null`

Same db, same table, same type, same parameter, different behaviour between the select and insert.

Comment: @CarlosBarroso, your case is exactly like the T-SQL example but with a `WHERE` clause instead of `IF` statement. I added a .NET example to illustrate the comparison behavior is the same. You mentioned same type but the type is different (SqlDbType.DateTime instead of SqlDbType.DateTime2).

Comment: In your TSQL you compare a sqlDatetime with sqlDatetime2 so the failure is expected, nothing in common with my behaviour.
But your .net sample reproduce perfectly the behaviour, i still dont understand why the insert will use the SqlDateTime2 and the Where use a rounded SqlDateTime, it's make no sense :)

Comment: @CarlosBarroso, your code (with AddWithValue) is also comparing different types, datetime (the parameter type) and datetime2 (the column type). That's why your code, the T-SQL code, and the PS script all exhibit the same behavior.